# jmeter CSV stops sample error

Tags: csv, jmeter, sample

My Jmeter with CSV stops after a sample error, even though the Thread Group is configured with continue.

My configuration is Thread Group, While Controler, Http Request, CSV Data set Config. The tests are working.

How can I enforce Jmeter to continue?

Comment: Does it stop because of an error, or because it reached end of file in CSV data set? What setting have you used in CSV Data Set Config?

Comment: **Thread Group**
- Action to be taken after a Sample error: continue

**CSV Data Set Config:**
-recycle on EOF: false
-Stop thread on EOF: true
-Sharing mode: All threads

See for the jmx file here:
[link](https://github.com/openfigis/figis/blob/master/jmeter/sitemapBased/dev.jmx)

Answer (score 0):

You have met one of the conditions that causes the while loop to stop (condition is blank):

> From help:
>
> The While Controller runs its children until the condition is "false".
>   Possible condition values:
>
> - blank - exit loop when last sample in loop fails
> - LAST - exit loop when last sample in loop fails. If the last sample just before the loop failed, don't enter loop.
> - Otherwise - exit (or don't enter) the loop when the condition is equal to the string "false"

You only have one sample in the loop, so when it produces an error, the blank condition (last sample in loop fails) is true, and the loop exits.

Try to use a value that becomes 'false' when you are ready to exit the loop, or anything else to keep it looping (ie "true").

Alternatively, if you add another sample that always succeeds (ie debug sampler) to the loop, you will see it keeps going, because the failing sample is no longer the last in the loop.